# How to render full image slowly pixel by pixel?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I want to render the parts of image slowly as shown in the attached image. How can I achieve this in iOS using Swift?[image]

Comment: What is the use case? Is the image downloaded slowly from the internet? Is it just for an artistic effect?

Comment: It is just an artistic effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a `CAShapeLayer` as a **Mask**.

If we start with this image:

[image]

and add a mask layer that looks like this (gray will actually be completely transparent):

[image]

overlaid on the image like this:

[image]

only the black parts of the mask will show (again, the gray part will be completely transparent):

[image]

So, if we calculate a grid of rectangles for the image:

[image]

we can then "randomly fill the grid" with black, looping to fill more and more grid spots, and the image will be "revealed" as in your gif.

Here's a quick example, using a 0.75-second repeating timer:

```
class RevealImageView: UIView {
    
    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imgView.image = image
        }
    }

    private let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    private let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    // array of rectangles that make up our grid
    private var gridOfRects: [CGRect] = []
    
    // we're going to use a 20x20 grid
    private var numRows: Int = 20
    private var numCols: Int = 20
    
    // counter for how many rectangles to reveal
    private var gridCounter: Int = 0
    
    // how many more rects each time
    private var gridIncrement: Int = 40
    
    // how long between steps (in seconds)
    private var stepTime: CFTimeInterval = 0.75
    
    // timer for updating the grid
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .white
        
        // add the image view and constrain all 4 sides
        addSubview(imgView)
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])

        // set the layer mask for the image view
        imgView.layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        // black rects will show that part of the image
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // this is when we know auto-layout has set the frame / bounds
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    @objc private func updateMask() -> Void {
        
        // increment number of rectangles to reveal
        gridCounter += gridIncrement
        
        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        
        for i in 0..<gridCounter {
            // don't go past the end of the array
            if i < gridOfRects.count {
                pth.append(UIBezierPath(rect: gridOfRects[i]))
            }
        }
        
        maskLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        // if image is fully revealed
        if gridCounter >= gridOfRects.count {
            // stop the repeating timer
            timer?.invalidate()
        }

    }
    
    // call this from the controller to start the reveal
    func startReveal() -> Void {

        // stop the timer if it's running
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        // empty grid array if it's being called again
        gridOfRects.removeAll()

        let rowHeight = bounds.height / CGFloat(numRows)
        let colWidth = bounds.width / CGFloat(numCols)
        
        var r: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: colWidth, height: rowHeight)
        
        // build array of grid rectangles
        for _ in 1...numRows {
            for _ in 1...numCols {
                gridOfRects.append(r)
                r.origin.x += colWidth
            }
            r.origin.x = 0
            r.origin.y += rowHeight
        }
        
        // shuffle the array so the rectangles are randomized
        gridOfRects.shuffle()

        // reset grid counter
        gridCounter = 0
        
        // do the first update
        updateMask()
        
        // set a repeating timer to continue the reveal
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: stepTime, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateMask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        if newSuperview == nil {
            // stop the timer if it's running
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }
    
}
```

and here's an example view controller class to see it in action:

```
class RevealImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var revealImageView: RevealImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        // make sure we can load an image
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "testing") else {
            print("Could not load image!!!")
            return
        }
        
        // create the view
        revealImageView = RevealImageView()
        
        // set the image
        revealImageView.image = img
        
        revealImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(revealImageView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            revealImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            revealImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            // use image size to keep proportions
            revealImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:revealImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width),
            revealImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // tap anywhere in the view to begin the reveal
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func didTap() -> Void {
        revealImageView.startReveal()
    }
    
}
```

How it looks on launch:

[image]

tap anywhere, and it looks like this after a couple seconds:

[image]

when it's fully "revealed" the timer stops and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks!