# How to show the image in a way that the pixels are shown cascading from top to bottom?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to display a UIImage on splash screen/ launch screen where the image will be shown such that the pixels look like they are cascading from top to bottom to display the full image. I donot have any snapshot of such animation but i have created the pixelated image as below:

```
    guard let currentCGImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.cgImage else {
        return
    }
    let currentCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: currentCGImage)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
    filter?.setValue(currentCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(12, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
    guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else { return }

    let context = CIContext()

    if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
        self.imgView.image = processedImage
    }
```

Does anybody has any idea of such animation?

Comment: What do you mean by cascading? Do you mean an effect where rows of pixels drop from above the image down to their destination row? That would be more like the image was sliced like a loaf of bread. Do you mean where rows of small blocks of pixels fall randomly from the top to build up the image? You need to provide a clear definition of the effect you are after before you can hope to code it.

Comment: Yes something like the blocks are hidden initially and then appear in a top down manner which just appears like the pixels are being popping up to create the full image.

Comment: So not falling from the top but popping into place in small rectangles. Can you edit your question to describe that goal more clearly then? And do you have any examples of the effect you are after that you can point to?

Comment: And are you saying that you want to start out with a pixellated image, and rectangle by rectangle, switch from solid color blocks to a detailed image? Again, please edit your question to provide a full description. Readers of this thread should not have to wade through a whole series of question-and-answer comments in order to divine your actual goal.

Comment: @S.V - do you mean something like this (except ordered top-to-bottom instead of random)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225165/how-to-render-full-image-slowly-pixel-by-pixel